# No service classes should use Java.util.date

Tags: java, unit-testing, archunit

Hi i want to write a ArchUnit test for service classes such that Fields are not allowed to be Date, So far i can accomplish something close to what i need by doing the following :

```
@Test
    public void all_public_methods_in_the_controller_layer_should_return_API_response_wrappers2() {
        JavaClasses importedClasses = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages("com.some.package");
        methods().that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().areAnnotatedWith(XmlAccessorType.class).and().areDeclaredInClassesThat().resideInAPackage("..webservice..").and().arePublic().and().haveNameMatching("Date").should().haveRawReturnType(SomeOtherDate.class).because("bla bla bla").check(importedClasses);
    }
```

But writing similar tests for Fields just pass even though the classes contain Date fields.

example :

```
  @Test
    public void some_architecture_rule22() {
        JavaClasses importedClasses = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages("com.some.package");
        fields().that().areDeclaredIn(SomeClass.java).and().arePrivate().and().haveRawType(Date.class).should().haveRawType(SomeOtherDate.class).because("bla bla bla").check(importedClasses);

    }
```

Comment: Is anything in your class allowed to be or use `java.util.Date`? If not, we can probably simplify this quite a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Knowing the specific details, I think your question could be simplified to how to prevent some classes to have fields of type java.util.Date.

In a small test project I prepared the following ArchRule and it seemed working:

```
ArchRuleDefinition.noFields().should().haveRawType(Date.class)
```